# Add custom font icons to visual composer

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm adding new icons to the Visual Composer iconbox in wordpress but i get the following 2 errors anyone know how to fix? Below is the code in my functions.php file

```
// Add new custom font to Font Family selection in icon box module
function myprefix_add_new_icon_set_to_iconbox( ) {
    $param = WPBMap::getParam( 'vcex_icon_box', 'icon_type' );
    $param['value'][__( 'CUSTOM ICONS NAME', 'total' )] = 'my_custom_icons';
    vc_update_shortcode_param( 'vcex_icon_box', $param );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'myprefix_add_new_icon_set_to_iconbox', 40 );

// Add font picker setting to icon box module when you select your font family from the dropdown
function myprefix_add_font_picker() {
    vc_add_param( 'vcex_icon_box', array(
            'type' => 'iconpicker',
            'heading' => esc_html__( 'Icon', 'total' ),
            'param_name' => 'my_custom_icons',
            'settings' => array(
                'emptyIcon' => true,
                'type' => 'my_custom_icons',
                'iconsPerPage' => 20,
            ),
            'dependency' => array(
                'element' => 'icon_type',
                'value' => 'my_custom_icons',
            ),
            'group' => esc_html__( 'Icon', 'total' ),
        )
    );
}
add_filter( 'vc_after_init', 'myprefix_add_font_picker', 40 );

// Add array of your fonts so they can be displayed in the font selector
function my_icon_array() {
    return array(
        array(
            'bg-icon-twitter' => 'Twitter',
            'bg-icon-user' => 'User'
        ));
}
add_filter( 'vc_iconpicker-type-my_custom_icons', 'my_icon_array' );
```

**Notice:**

> Wrong name for shortcode:vcex_icon_box. Name required in
>   /home/.../plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php
>   on line 472

**Warning:**

> Cannot use a scalar value as an array in
>   /home/.../plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-wpb-map.php 
>   on line 367

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 1 is caused by the fact you don't have a shortcode in your installation called "vcex_icon_box". Try "vc_icon" instead.

Also, if you use vc_icon, you will need to change the dependency element to `type` and not `icon_type`.

For error 2, `WPBMap::getParam( 'vcex_icon_box', 'icon_type' );` is returning a scalar value, which you can then treat it like an array.

As a debug tip, its a good idea to test the outputs of functions so you understand what you are getting.

The VC documentation is also not the greatest.